# Python 3 with NumPy and object references

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I need to create a large matrix (array) structure (3 axis) and each element should store the reference to a Python object (myclass instance). Is it possible to use numpy to create such an array. Which data type should I use in order to store Python references?
The advantage of numpy is the support of slicing at different levels. The alternativee is to create a nested (nested) list but it is a cumbersome solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `dtype=object` to store Python objects in the array.

```
import numpy as np

class Foo: pass

arr=np.empty(2,dtype=object)
arr[:]=[Foo(),Foo()]
print(arr)
# [<__main__.Foo instance at 0xb7827d0c>
#  <__main__.Foo instance at 0xb748b5ac>]

print(arr.dtype)
# object
```

Comment: If you're curious you can inspect that NumPy simply stores pointers to the objects in the array of dtype `object`: `x = object(); a = np.array([x, x]); print (id(x), id(x)) == struct.unpack('2L',ctypes.string_at(a.ctypes.data, 8))` (32-bit Python).

Comment: @eryksun: You can simply replace `ctypes.string_at(a.ctypes.data, 8)` with the simpler and more general `a.tostring()`.

Comment: @eryksun: +1'd your comments: `ctypes.string_at()` is indeed an interesting function. :)

Answer (score 1):

Just give `object` as the dtype, and you can store anything you want.

```
import numpy

print numpy.array([['a', (2, 2)], [1, 2+3j], [open, xrange(7)]], dtype=object)
```

Any unrecognized type will work this way, so you might want to use `myclass` instead of `object`. `object` just makes it clear that you'll be storing arbitrary objects without any numpy optimization. See [the docs](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.dtypes.html#specifying-and-constructing-data-types) for more info.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to do anything special: this works out of the box:

```
>>> import numpy
>>> class TheClass(object):
...     pass
... 
>>> numpy.array([TheClass(), TheClass()])

array([<__main__.TheClass object at 0x10d435a50>,
       <__main__.TheClass object at 0x10d435a90>], dtype=object)
```

NumPy automatically detects that the array objects are not of one of its standard scalar types (float, int, etc.) and handles this by automatically setting `dtype` to `object`.